# Read in one word from a file and comparing with a regular expression

Tags: c, regex, file, line

I am building a program that is suppose to look for words from a file that has 2 vowels in a row and ends with either ly or ing. Im currently having some issues with how i am suppose to deal with reading words from the file. My current code looks a little like this

```
fgets(string, BUFF_SIZE, file);
char *ptr = strtok(string, delim);
reti = regcomp(&regex, "[aoueiyAOUEIY]+[aoueiyAOUEIY].{0,}(ly|ing|LY|ING)$", REG_EXTENDED);
if (reti){
   fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
   exit(1);
}
/* Execute regular expression */

reti = regexec(&regex, ptr , 0, NULL, 0);
if (!reti) {
   puts("Match");
  printf(" %s\n", string);
}
else if (reti == REG_NOMATCH) {
   puts("No match");
   printf(" %s\n", string);
}
else {
   regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
   fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
   exit(1);
}
```

Im aware that i need some sort of loop so that i can check more then one word,i wanted to try how strtok would work but realised that i stil face the same problem. If i for example have the line fairly standing. jumping? hoping! there is just to many "chars" that a word can end on, how to i make my delim understand that it's at an end of a word. Im thinking of doing a second regex that only has letter in it and compare until i get a reg no match. But the issue with that is that the buffer will get full very quickly.

Comment: If you just want to read space-delimited "words", why not use `fscanf`  to read them? As in `while (fscanf(file, "%99s", string) == 1) { /* check the word in string... */ }` (assuming `BUFF_SIZE` is `100`, adjust as needed).

Comment: If your problem is to get "words one at the time" from a file, there is no need for all the regex code. Simplify the question to only contain the problematic part.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude thanks for the answer, but if i do that then the word ending with '?' for example will include de '?' and my regex will not match it.

Comment: @4386427 Well the regex is as much part of the problem, i need to read one word from a file so that the regex understands it. I need to somehow make the regex understand that if i read in the word fairly? it's suppose to only match the things before the '?' sign

Comment: @forsb Seems to me you are mixing two problems. a) How to read words b) How to write the regex. I'll recommend that you solve them one by one.

Comment: OT: Seems the regex is case sensitive for the ending but case insensitive for the vowels. Is that intended? Perhaps consider to turn the word into all-lower-case before apllying the regex

Comment: Are you required to use regex for this?

Comment: @4386427 I would say that i can solve those problems on their own, the ending should not be case sensitive, it can end on either ly or LY etc. i am required to use regex for this yes

Comment: @forsb Okay. So if your problem is words with special characters in the end, i.e. like "fairly?" of "fairly!", just write a function to remove the special characters before applying the regex.

Comment: @4386427 Yes i guess that could be a step in the right direction, i will try this and se if the result gets better, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a task like this it's important to define "what is a word".

For instance consider "bad!idea this!is" is that the 4 words "bad", "idea" "this" "is" or is it the 4 words "bad!", "idea" "this!" "is" or is it just the two words "bad!idea" "this!is".

And what if the input is "bad3idea this9is" ?

Sometimes the standard functions (e.g. `strtok`, `fscanf`) will fit your needs and in such cases you should use them.

In case the standard functions do not fit, you can use `fgetc` to implement something that fit your needs.

The example below will consider anything that is **not** a letter (i.e. not a-z or A-Z) as word delimiters.

```
int end_of_file = 0;
while(!end_of_file)
{
    int index = 0;
    int c = fgetc(file);
    if (c == EOF) break;  // Done with the file
    while (isalpha(c))
    {
        string[index] = c;
        ++index;
        if (index == BUFF_SIZE)
        {
            // oh dear, the buffer is too small
            //
            // Just end the program... 
            exit(1);
        }
        c = fgetc(file);
        if (c == EOF)
        {
            end_of_file = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    string[index] = '\0';
    if (index >= 4)       // We need at least 4 chars for a match
    {
        // do the regex stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i did something similar to this, my issue was that words like way--marking are suppose to count, so i had to make a special case for '-' but used isalpha for the rest. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @forsb You can always extend the list of things that is **not** a delimiter. For instance: `while (isalpha(c))` --> `while (isalpha(c) || (c == `-`))` will accept a `-` as a legal character in a word.

Comment: I checked if it was a nomatch and in the case that it was !isalpha i emptied the buffer and if it was '-' it continued. Thanks for all the help gotten in togheter now!